# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 PHP8.1.x

Tags: php, mysql

I found little problem in my CRUD. When I run the PHP code in version 7.4.x it work just fine. But when i deploy this site on server with PHP ver. 8.1.x I getting this error:

```
<pre>Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\user.inc.php:53

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\user.inc.php(53): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\ajax.php(40): User->getRow('id', '1')
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\user.inc.php on line 53</pre>
```

Do you have any idea, where the problem can be? Thanks

ajax.php:

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if(!empty($action)){
    require_once 'user.inc.php';
    $obj=new User();    
}

//adding user action
if($action=='adduser' && !empty($_POST)){
    $name=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $photo=$_FILES['photo'];

    $playerId=(!empty($_POST['userid']))? $_POST['userid']: "";

    $imagename="";
    if(!empty($photo['name'])){
        $imagename=$obj->uploadPhoto($photo);
        $playerData=[
            'firstname'=>$name,
            'lastname'=>$lastname,
            'email'=>$email,
            'photo'=>$imagename,
        ];
    }else{
        $playerData=[
            'firstname'=>$name,
            'lastname'=>$lastname,
            'email'=>$email,
        ];
    }
$playerId=$obj->add($playerData);
if(!empty($playerId)){
    $player=$obj->getRow('id',$playerId);
    echo json_encode($player);
    exit();
}
}


?>
```

and here is user.inc.php

```
    // fuction to get single row
    public function getRow($field,$value)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$field}=:{$field}";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            $result = [];
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is in your ```user.inc.php```, particularly the lines before the ```PDOStatement->execute()``` line?

Comment: Please include that in your post.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use ```{$field}=:{$field}```?

Answer (score 0):

I just not think straight. The problem was so obvious...

code with error:

```
// fuction to get single row
    public function getRow($field,$value)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$field}=:{$field}";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            $result = [];
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

fixed code:

```
// fuction to get single row
    public function getRow($field, $value)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$field}=:{$field}";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([":{$field}"=> $value]);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            $result = [];
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Honestly I don't know what I was thinking... Sometimes you need to step back away from the project and after you come back it will pop up to you. Any way, now its working. Thanks